# Converting Jquery to Vanilla JS stuck on AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert an older jquery script to vanilla JS.

I have been working through most of them just one by one but am having a problem with the ajax call.  Can anyone look at my original file and new file and see what is missing?

***I am struggling mostly with converting the initial function calls to vanilla js. If you look at the 2nd code drop there most of the 'jquery-isms' have been rewritten in vanilla js. However I am having trouble converting my $.merge and $.extend actions. Furthermore, converting the $.ajax call to a JS version.***

I tried to work on it modularly task by task but still haven't gotten it completely polished.

Jquery

```
(function($){

    $(document).ready(function() {
      
      $.ajax({
        
        
        url: "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.galleries.getPhotos&api_key=*PRIVATE*c&gallery_id=72157720949295872&per_page=10&format=json&nojsoncallback=1",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("api successfully called")
    
          let path = data.photos.photo
          //for each photo, I save the different individual ids into variables so that they can be easily plugged into a URL
          for (let i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
            let obj = path[i];
            let farm_id = data.photos.photo[i].farm
            let server_id = data.photos.photo[i].server
            let photo_id = data.photos.photo[i].id
            let secret = data.photos.photo[i].secret
    
          //the static address to photos on Flickr is accessed through this address: https://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/{server-id}/{id}_{secret}.jpg
          //this variable is the direct link to access photos on Flickr, minus the ".jpg" designation that will be added, according to whether we are trying to access the medium picture or the large picture
            let pic_url = "https://farm" + farm_id + ".staticflickr.com/" + server_id + "/" + photo_id + "_" + secret;
    
            //this is the variable that stores the medium jpeg URL
            let pic_url_m = pic_url + "_m.jpg";
    
            //this stores an image tag which will be populated with a medium jpeg URL
            let pic_img = ('<img src=\'' + pic_url_m + '\' alt = \"pic\" />');
          
            //this appends the var pic_img to the photo_list div as the function loops through
    
            //$('.body').append('#frame');
            $('#photo-list').append(pic_img);
    
            //this appends the class "paginate" to each img tag that is formed, ensuring that the the divs get passed to a later function called customPaginate
          //  $('img').addClass("paginate")
            $('#photo-list img').addClass("paginate");
            
          }
    
          //this passes all divs with the class "pagination" to the function customPaginate
          $('.pagination').customPaginate({
                itemsToPaginate: ".paginate"
            });
    
          //when img tags with the class paginate are clicked, the following function is called
          $('.paginate').click(function() {
    
            //this variable saves the "src" or URL of (this) which is any element with the class "paginate"
            let src = $(this).attr('src');
    
            //this variable takes the "src" variable, slices the last six characters, and replaces it with "_c.jpg", a large version of the image URL
            let src_l = src.slice(0, -6) + "_c.jpg";
    
            //gives the "frame img" element a new attribute, which is the large image URL
           $('#frame img').attr('src', src_l);
    
            //allows the the "frame img" element to fade into the screen
           $('#frame img').fadeIn();
    
            //allows the "overlay" element to fade onto the screen
            $('#overlay').fadeIn();
    
            //when the "overlay" element is clicked, both the "overlay" and "frame img" elements 
            $('#overlay').click(function() {
              $(this).fadeOut();
              $('#frame img').fadeOut();
    
            //removes the "src" attribute from "frame img", allowing it to be populated by other image URLs next time an image is clicked 
              $('#frame img').removeAttr('src');
              });
            });
          }
        });
      });
    
    //this function generates the customPaginate function, which paginates the images 10 to a page
      $.fn.customPaginate = function(options)
        {
          let paginationContainer = this;
               
          let defaults = {
            //sets how many items to a page
              itemsPerPage : 10
               };
            
          let settings = {};
          
          //merges defaults and options into one one variable, settings 
          $.extend(settings, defaults, options);
          
          //sets how many items will be on each page     
          let itemsPerPage = settings.itemsPerPage;
           
          //sets which items are going to be 
          let itemsToPaginate = $(settings.itemsToPaginate);
    
          //determines how many pages to generate based on the amount of items 
          let numberOfItems = Math.ceil((itemsToPaginate.length / itemsPerPage));
              
          //this ul will contain the page numbers
          $("<ul></ul>").prependTo(paginationContainer);
               
          //loops through the ul tag the same number of times as there are pages. in this case, the loop will run 4 times
          for(let index = 0; index < numberOfItems; index++)
          {
            paginationContainer.find('ul').append('<li>'+ (index+1) + '</li>');
          }
    
          //ensures that the current page only displays the items that should be on the specific page, and hides the others
          itemsToPaginate.filter(":gt(" + (itemsPerPage - 1)  + ")").hide();
               
          //locates the first li element, adds activeClass element to it
          paginationContainer.find("ul li").first().addClass(settings.activeClass).end().on('click', function(){
             
          let $this = $(this);
                 
          //gives current page the activeClass setting
          $this.addClass(settings.activeClass);
             
          //takes activeClass setting away from non-current pages
          $this.siblings().removeClass(settings.activeClass);
               
          let pageNumber = $this.text();
                  
          //this variable designates that items located on the previous page times the number of items per page should be hidden
          let itemsToHide = itemsToPaginate.filter(":lt(" + ((pageNumber-1) * itemsPerPage)  + ")");
    
          //this function merges itemsToHide and itemsToPaginate that are greater than the product of the pageNumber and the itemsPerPage minus 1, ensuring that these items are hidden from view
          $.merge(itemsToHide, itemsToPaginate.filter(":gt(" + ((pageNumber * itemsPerPage) - 1)  + ")"));
                    
          //designates these items as items that should be shown on the current page
          let itemsToShow = itemsToPaginate.not(itemsToHide);
    
          //hides items from other pages and shows items from current page
          $("html,body").animate({scrollTop:"0px"}, function(){
              itemsToHide.hide();
              itemsToShow.show();
            });
        });
      }
    
    }(jQuery));
```

Vanilla JS (**what im still stuck on**)

```
(function($){

    document.querySelector(document).ready(function() {
      
      $.ajax({   //need to convert this to JS
        
        
        url: "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.galleries.getPhotos&api_key=*PRIVATE*c&gallery_id=72157720949295872&per_page=10&format=json&nojsoncallback=1",
        type: "GET",
        success: function(data) {
          console.log("api successfully called")
                        // ....truncated
          }
        });
      });
    
      $.fn.customPaginate = function()
        {
          let paginationContainer = this;
               
          let defaults = {
              itemsPerPage : 10
               };
            
          let settings = {};
          
          //need to convert this extend to JS
          $.extend(settings, defaults, options);
          
          let itemsPerPage = settings.itemsPerPage;
           
         // ....truncated
               
          let pageNumber = qS.text();
                  
          let itemsToHide = itemsToPaginate.filter(":lt(" + ((pageNumber-1) * itemsPerPage)  + ")");
    
          //need to convert this extend to JS
          $.merge(itemsToHide, itemsToPaginate.filter(":gt(" + ((pageNumber * itemsPerPage) - 1)  + ")"));
                    
        });
      }
    }(jQuery));
```

Comment: Please edit your question and remove the code drop.  Edit it down to the smallest code segment that demonstrates the problem you're having.  Also, please add details about the problem you've encountered.  Your question is not clear other than you saying you have a problem with the AJAX part.  What exactly is the problem you're having with the AJAX call?

Comment: I am struggling mostly with converting the initial function calls to vanilla js. If you look at the 2nd code drop there most of the 'jquery-isms' have been rewritten in raw js. However I am having trouble converting my $.merge and $.extend actions. Furthermore, converting the $.ajax call to a JS version.

Comment: So learn how to use xmlhttprequest or fetch to make the call. For the extension, you need to make a function and pass in data. I doubt anyone is going to have the time to do a lot of it because that is not a small task. `function customPaginate(elem) { }` <-- pass in the elem instead of this.

Comment: Unfortunately, struggling with converting to vanilla js is outside the scope of questions considered on-topic for this site.  This site expects a narrowly defined question that has an answer that can be deemed as right or wrong.  General questions asking for "please help me accomplish this task" are not narrowly defined problems.

Comment: @devlincarnate I have updated my question and trimmed my Vanilla JS to what I am stuck on, apologies for being out of scope

Answer (score 0):

First, please see: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp

Example you might consider.

```
function getPages(){
  const xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onload = function() {
    // Everything you want to do with the data
    // this.responseText.photos.photo
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.galleries.getPhotos&api_key=*PRIVATE*c&gallery_id=72157720949295872&per_page=10&format=json&nojsoncallback=1",);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```